# Test for list without duplicated elements

Tags: python, duplicates, python-3.3

There aren't a set of instructions, but I basically have to write a code for `def hasNoDuplicate` and it returns `True` exactly when list has no duplicates. This is what I've written, I'm new to programming so all of this is very overwhelming. I don't know exactly what to put in the `if` statement. Any advice would help a lot!

```
def hasNoDuplicates(values):
    foundCounterExampleYet = False
    for value in values:
        if():
            foundCounterExampleYet = True
    return not(foundCounterExampleYet)
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @killermonkey50 yes sorry!

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Think this through carefully; how would *you* decide whether a list had duplicate items or not?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts of something you might be able to try?  THere are a lot of ways to do this.  Post some ideas and people can give you some feedback.  Here's a hint:  Looks like you're going through each of your values one by one.  How might you tell whether a value has already been seen?

Comment: Determine what kind of datastructure that you need to use. Then figure out how to insert values into it and how to query it for membership.

Comment: @CarolineRodgers cyber's way will work well, but try to figure it out on your own.  This is a basic step in your programming education--don't take his/her shortcut.

Comment: @thumbtackthief from what I've learned so far in this course, we either use a "There exits" or a "for all" statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def hasNoDuplicates(values):
    foundCounterExampleYet = False
    value = None
    while values:
       value = values.pop()
       if value in values:
           foundCounterExampleYet = True
           break
    return not(foundCounterExampleYet)
```

Now you get:

```
>>> hasNoDuplicates([1,2,3])
True
>>> hasNoDuplicates([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,4])
False
>>>
```

What this code does is, it takes the input list, and one by one takes out the last element from the list and checks if the item exists in the list. If it exists, then a duplication is detected, and it changes the value of `foundCounterExampleYet` and consequently jumps out of the loop. This checking happens until the list becomes empty. `while values` means *do this while the list is not empty*

The `pop` method takes out the last element from the list. But it has side effect, meaning it changes the value of the initial input:

```
>>> [1,2,3].pop()
3
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Could you give some additional explanations? What does the code do, and why? I think this approach is more suitable for the OP than Cyber's answer.

Comment: Sure, I added some explanation. I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can store the values in a `set` as you're looping through the inputs, and use the `in` operator to check for membership in that `set`. See my comments alongside the following code.

```
def hasNoDuplicates(values):
    currentValues = set()              # initialize an empty set
    for value in values:               # iterate over your inputs
        if value in currentValues:     # if the current value is in your set, there is a duplicate
            return False
        else:
            currentValues.add(value)   # no duplicate exists, add it to the set
    return True                        # If it made it through all the values, there were no duplicates
```

For fun, there is an easier way to do this. If the items in the `values` sequence are hashable, you can make a `set` from the whole sequence. Since by definition a `set` may not have any duplicates, if the length of the original sequence is the same length as the `set`, then all items are unique. If the `set` is shorter, there was at least one duplicate.

```
def hasNoDuplicates(values):
    return len(values) == len(set(values))
```